# How to create a custom notification preview inside activity when app is in background

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I create a custom notifier like a notification to show when app is in background and new notification is received.

I will like to preview few notification content inside activity, like `title` and 'message' of the notification content, then hide it after some second.

Please how do I do this instead of using `toast`?

[image]

Comment: Use notifications. You can show Activity from the background but that is the worst idea, as your application is not running but can show a popup.

Comment: @PankajKumar am using notification, but when app is running the notification won't show so I only need this to show wen broadcast-receiver broadcast new notification